# How do I get specific dynamic id

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

This is my dynamic id from database.

```
<input type="hidden" name="getID" value="<?php echo $row['ID']; ?>">
<input type="submit" name="getbtn" value="Get ID">
```

How do I get the specific dynamic ID and display the other ID each click I do.

Example:
Output 1
ID
1

Output 2
ID
1
2

Output 3
ID
1
2
3

Comment: I don't understand which are the problem. Please, can you explain more details or write other example.

Comment: For example, If I click the button the output should be 1, and If I click it again it will show the 1 and 2 ID. Just like increment but it depends whenever I click.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/7dbwxyt7/ in this case set ID in 3 and show output with javascript alert

Answer (score 0):

I write this answer to close your question ;)

```
<input type="hidden" name="getID" id="getID" value="3" count="3">
<input type="submit" id="subm" name="getbtn" value="Get ID" onclick="getId();">
<br /><br />

function getId() {
    id = $("#getID").attr('count');

  idnew = parseInt(id) + 1;
  $("#getID").attr('count', idnew);
  value = $("#getID").val();
  /*alert(value);*/
  $("#showOutput").val(value);
  $("#getID").val(value + " " +idnew);

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Cuchu/7dbwxyt7/